# File not found while using sqlite3.h library while programming in C

Tags: c, sqlite

I am having a problem in windows 10 in VS Code while using sqlite3.I have added all the files from this website(https://github.com/LuaDist/libsqlite3/blob/master/sqlite3.h) to folder with my main.c and where is my test.db.Error I am getting while defaulty launching code via coderunner is :

main.c:2:21: fatal error: sqlite3.h: No such file or directory
 #include 
                     ^
compilation terminated.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sqlite3.h> 

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   sqlite3 *db;
   char *zErrMsg = 0;
   int rc;

   rc = sqlite3_open("test.db", &db);

   if( rc ) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
      return 1;
   } else {
      fprintf(stderr, "Opened database successfully\n");
   }
   sqlite3_close(db);
}
```

All help is appreciated

Comment: if it's a local header that's part of your project, use `#include "sqlite3.h"` instead.

Comment: C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Local\Temp\ccyPrZXA.o:main.c:(.text+0x26): undefined reference to `sqlite3_open'
C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Local\Temp\ccyPrZXA.o:main.c:(.text+0x3d): undefined reference to `sqlite3_errmsg'
C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Local\Temp\ccyPrZXA.o:main.c:(.text+0x94): undefined reference to `sqlite3_close'

Answer (score 2):

I am very sorry I have found out solution.I had to change
`#include <sqlite3.h>`
to

`#include "sqlite3.h"`

and place sqlite3.c into folder with my main.c .And to compile this code I had to write:
`gcc main.c sqlite3.c`